# Python function that will return items from two lists that are the same

Tags: python, list, function

> Write a function `printCommonLetters()`that has two input arguments:
>   `lst1` and `lst2`, which are two lists of strings.
>   The function will print the items that are the same in both lists.
>   When you are done iterating over both loops, print a final statement like ‘done’ or ‘goodbye’.
>
> We discussed in class how execution resumes with non-indented statement that is aligned with for in the for loop statement.

For example if

```
lst1 = [ ‘ab’, ‘cd’, ‘ef’, ‘gh’] 
lst2 = [‘abc’, ’geh’, ‘cd’, ‘ab’],
```

the function will print:

```
‘ab’

‘cd’  
‘goodbye!’
```

I have found shorthanded way to do it, but not a full function. I have it giving me back `['ab', 'abc']`, but cant get it to give me the `'cd'`...

here is what I have so far:

```
def printCommonLetters( lst1, lst2):
    for i in lst1:
       for j in lst2:
            if i is not j:
               return[i,j]

print( printCommonLetters( [ 'ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh'],['abc', 'geh', 'cd', 'ab'] ))

print('goodbye!')
```

Comment: I would recommend that you investigate Python's set operations

Comment: Please fix the formatting in your question.

Comment: This is the way the professor gave it to me, sorry about the format of the question, but I literally took it right from the hw.

Comment: I know someone says this is a duplicate question, but that is not the format my professor wants for it

Answer (score 0):

That's what you need. No iteration, just `set`.

```
print set(list1)&set(list2)
```

Comment: That gave me the output I wanted! thank you so much!! is there a way to make it go down instead of... {'ab', 'cd'} but would give:
'ab'
'cd'

not sure why she wants it that specific format, but I appreciate the help to get the outcome!